# How to set PyCharm not to open all last projects?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a question when it comes to PyCharm IDE. It seems that it is set by default to open all last projects when started, and I would like to start with no projects opened. For instance, I have worked on two projects until now and when I start PyCharm it opens both of them.

Comment: The answer is in fact not right. In PyCharm one project is made up of all the projects opened in a single Project View. Meaning that to open only 1 project you'd have to explicitly close the other project, provided both are opened in the same window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This option is located in Settings:

> Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Startup/Shutdown > Reopen last project on startup

Also, you can use search with "last project".

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you open the preferences and search for "Start" you will find this:

[image]

You can untick this and it will start at the project selection screen.