# Start where I left off in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

Valid under help centre guidelines:*software tools commonly used by programmers*.
I would like to start PyCharm and for it to automatically open the programs I had open when I closed PyCharm in the previous session (i.e. **start where I left off**).
I usually have several concurrent programs from very different locations, so finding them all manually is a pain.
Is there a way this can happen automatically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set PyCharm not to open all last projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43180749/how-to-set-pycharm-not-to-open-all-last-projects)

Comment: No, see comments on accepted answer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check a checkbox in the Preferences. It's on the path:

```
Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Reopen last project on startup
```

Comment: Ah indeed, I have this checked yet I still do not get the projects opening on startup.

Comment: @tomdavison It should open up all programs that were open when Pycharm was terminated. Which OS are you using and how are you terminating Pycharm?

Comment: I thought it should yes, but instead I return to the Pycharm welcome window and have to start over. I am running on Ubuntu, and have tried terminating through the 'x' close button, as well as the 'Exit' option in the File menu. Thanks!

Comment: @tomdavison If you close the window with the x-button then you're closing the project, not closing pycharm. If you close all projects then there won't be any projects to open up to. You should be terminating the application instead, but I'm not using pycharm on Ubuntu so don't know for sure. It may be that you need a system restart, but that would be weird.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information. How else can one possibly close pycharm, if not using the two close options? I believe the projects all remain in open in the program as I close it?

Comment: @tomdavison Closing from the file menu seems correct; I was just commenting about closing the individual windows.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help, seems to be an issue with the program rather than something I am doing wrong then. I'll try to figure a work around, thanks!